# Problems using frontend in webapages with applicationinsights

Tags: web-applications

I have this problem in using application insights, the same started yesterday 08/29/2017, I already identified that occurs in the application frontend in the use of the script that is inserted in the masterpage.

**var appInsights = window.appInsights || Function (config) {function r (config) {t [config] = function () {var i = arguments; (S) = sv = sv = sv = sv = sv = svv = svv = svv = svv = svv = U.createElement (o), i, f; For (s.src = config.url || "//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js", u.getElementsByTagName (o) [0] .parentNode.appendChild (s), T.cookie = u.cookie, t.queue = [], i = ["Event", "Exception", "Metric", "PageView", "Trace" I.pop ()); Return r ("setAuthenticatedUserContext"), r ("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"), config.disableExceptionTracking || (Config, r, u, e, o) {var s = f && f (config, r, u, R, u, e, o), return s! ==! 0 && t ["_" + i] (config, r, u, = Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey%> "}); Window.appInsights = appInsights; AppInsights.trackPageView ();**

**error:
Unhandled exception at line 2, column 3681 in http://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Can not get the 'apply' property of an undefined or null reference.**

Is someone having this problem or has it already had the same problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We also had this problem but today everything started to work fine. Did Microsoft fixed something? I'm lookin at the Azure Application insight Status but there is no reference to this script problem.

[Azure Application insight Status](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/applicationinsights-status)